# Reading data from serial AT device

Tags: c#, uwp, serial-port, at-command

The only way I was able to read data from a serial AT device (that is a serial device that "speaks" only AT commands) was by reading one byte at a time.

The problem is that if I try to read more than I get from the device the code freezes, the LoadAsync method never returns. My solution was to read one byte at a time and use a cancellation token that would cancel the task if it did not return after some milliseconds.

```
 public async Task<DeviceResponse> ReadStringInBatchAsync(int timeoutMilliseconds)
        {

            readCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            readCancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter(timeoutMilliseconds);


            Task<UInt32> loadAsyncTask;

            DeviceDataReader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
            UInt32 bytesRead = 0;
            string response = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                do
                {
                    loadAsyncTask = DeviceDataReader.LoadAsync(1).AsTask(readCancellationTokenSource.Token);
                    bytesRead = await loadAsyncTask;
                    response += DeviceDataReader.ReadString(bytesRead);
                } while (bytesRead > 0);
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
            readCancellationTokenSource?.Dispose();

            return new DeviceResponse() { FullResponse = response };

        }
```

Any idea why this is happening? I tried with non-AT devices and there was no problem reading more than 1 byte. I have also tried with 2 different AT devices and both of them behaved the same way.

Comment: How are you calling the `ReadStringInBatchAsync` method?

Comment: @DavidG var response = await deviceReader.ReadStringInBatchAsync(200);

Comment: The call is async all the way up, I am not blocking on the async..

Comment: Try update the `LoadAsync` as follows: ` var bytesRead = await DeviceDataReader.LoadAsync(1);
  while (bytesRead  >= 1)
  {
     bytesRead  = await DeviceDataReader.LoadAsync(1);
  }`